# how do I test grail's controller's render method?

Tags: testing, grails, render, controllers

How do I test this:

```
render view: "create", model: [user: user]
```

I know how to test redirectArgs and stuff, but I can't find an example to test something like this. It seems like articles and stuff go out of their way to not test this....

Comment: What would you want to test here?

Comment: Basically everything. Tinny got it. He showed how to test the view and the model since there is no return from the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`renderArgs` is what you want. (From `ControllerUnitTestCase`)

E.g to test that the correct view will be rendered

```
assertEquals 'create', renderArgs.view
```

Check the model

```
assertEquals user, renderArgs.model.user
```

Make sure that your test extends `ControllerUnitTestCase`

Etc etc

Comment: Thanks. I hate the fact that groovy is dynamic, so code completion wouldn't just tell me this. And you'd think between ibm developer works and grails testing section, it would have mentioned this. I mean, it shows EVERY OTHER EXAMPLE except for this one... which is actually the most common! Makes me angry :/ Thank you very much tinny.

Comment: Dynamic typing has its trade offs, but makes so much of the Grails framework voodoo possible. "The Definitive Guide to Grails" has a good section on controller testing p91. Also renderArgs is mentioned in the API docs http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/api/grails/test/ControllerUnitTestCase.html